# Reference on properties of the queen graph $Q_n$?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, chessboard

I am looking for a reference on the graph approach of the $n$-queens problem, basically something on the various properties of the $Q_n$ graph.

I have a pretty good background on regular graph theory but none experience on the $n$-queens problem itself so I'm looking for something directed to readers of that kind of level.

If it could be a book on that specific subject it would be better but probably there are only papers, so paper references are also ok.

Any good recs?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following survey article: Bell, Jordan; Stevens, Brett A survey of known results and research areas for n-queens. Discrete Math. 309 (2009), no. 1, 1–31.

You may also find the following book interesting and useful: Watkins, John J. Across the board: the mathematics of chessboard problems. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 2004.